# How do I make my limit match greedy?

Tags: javascript, regex

The following code only matches `MN`. How do I get it to match `KDMN`?

```
var str = ' New York Stock Exchange (NYSE) under the symbol "KDMN."';
var patt = new RegExp("symbol.+([A-Z]{2,5})");
var res = patt.exec(str);
console.log(res[1]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a lazy `+?` quantifier:

```
/symbol.+?([A-Z]{2,5})/
         ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eU0gP5/1). If you keep the greedy `.+`, it will match as many characters as possible, and will only leave the minimum 2 chars for the next subpattern.

Or, I'd rather make this a bit more verbose:

```
/symbol\s+"([A-Z]{2,5})/
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eU0gP5/2). The `symbol` matches a literal string `symbol`, `\s+` will match 1 or more whitespaces, `"` will match a double quote, and `([A-Z]{2,5})` will capture 2 to 5 uppercase ASCII letters into Group 1.

Comment: Thank you. Whats the advantage of making it more verbose?

Comment: Better backtracking control, you know what patterns you are matching, and faster execution. If the pattern is not known, you may still fall back to using lazy quantifier with `.`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer